# Function which gets executed on library load

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am pretty new in developing Shared Libraries for the Linux platform.

Is there a function that I can define inside the .SO that will be called upon the load of the library by `dlopen()` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using GCC or a compatible compiler, you can declare a function with `__attribute__((constructor))` and it will be called upon load. Something like

```
__attribute__((constructor))
void init()
{
    puts("Hello dynamic linkage world!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no standard "entry point" in a shared object defined by the system.  A given application that uses `dlopen()` is likely to define a standard symbol name to be used as the entry point for modules loaded this way.  The host application would then use `dlsym()` to look up that symbol by name in order to invoke it.

But most applications do not use dlopen directly at all--and you haven't explained why you think you should.

Comment: why they don't use dlopen directly ?

Comment: Normal applications do not use it directly, because they are explicitly linked to their required shared libraries at build time.  That is, instructions are baked into every executable telling the loader which libraries to load, without any explicit code in the application.  You can see which libraries will be automatically loaded in this way by running the program `ldd` on an executable.  Explicit use of `dlopen()` is for programs which implement a "plugin" architecture for example--programs which do not know which libraries they need until runtime.  Examples: Firefox, Python, Photoshop....

Answer (score 1):

from man page:
**The obsolete symbols _init() and _fini()**
 The linker recognizes special symbols _init and _fini.  If a dynamic
       library exports a routine named _init(), then that code is executed
       after the loading, before dlopen() returns.  If the dynamic library
       exports a routine named _fini(), then that routine is called just
       before the library is unloaded.  In case you need to avoid linking
       against the system startup files, this can be done by using the
       gcc(1) -nostartfiles command-line option.

```
   Using these routines, or the gcc -nostartfiles or -nostdlib options,
   is not recommended.  Their use may result in undesired behavior,
   since the constructor/destructor routines will not be executed
   (unless special measures are taken).

   **Instead, libraries should export routines using the
   __attribute__((constructor)) and __attribute__((destructor)) function
   attributes.  See the gcc info pages for information on these.
   Constructor routines are executed before dlopen() returns, and
   destructor routines are executed before dlclose() returns.**
```